# "Mark assemblies with assembly version" in Visual Studio 2022 preview

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

After that I upgrade a NET Framework 4.8 project to NET Core 7.0 I'm getting the suggestion message "Mark assemblies with assembly version" in Visual Studio 2022 preview, in projects that already has this tag specified, for example:

[image]

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>
    </RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>blah blah blah</AssemblyName>
    <MyType>Windows</MyType>
    <AssemblyVersion>5.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>5.0</FileVersion>
    <NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>true</ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>..\..\..\Bin\AnyCPU\Debug\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MyType>Empty</MyType>
    <AssemblyTitle>blah blah blah.dll</AssemblyTitle>
    <Description>blah blah blah</Description>
    <Company>blah blah blah</Company>
    <Product>blah blah blah</Product>
    <Copyright>blah blah blah © 2023</Copyright>
    <AssemblyVersion>5.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>5.0</FileVersion>
    <NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Is this a false positive or I'm missing something?.

I know that I can suppress this suggestion message, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something or it is just a bug.

Deleting the hidden ".vs" folder, cleaning the project,realoding it and rebuilding it does not fix this issue.

The help link for the suggestion message refers to the usage of an attribute class in the AssemblyInfo.vb/AssemblyInfo.cs file, but I'm not sure if this applies to .NET core or only for MyProject\AssemblyInfo.vb in a .NET Framework project.

This is the AssemblyInfo.vb that the .NET Framework 4.8 project had when upgraded it to NET Core 7.0:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Resources

<Assembly: AssemblyTitle("blah blah blah.dll")>
<Assembly: AssemblyDescription("blah blah blah")>
<Assembly: AssemblyCompany("blah blah blah")>
<Assembly: AssemblyProduct("blah blah blah")>
<Assembly: AssemblyCopyright("blah blah blah © 2023")>
<Assembly: AssemblyTrademark("blah blah blah")>

<Assembly: ComVisible(False)>

<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("5.0")>
<Assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("5.0")>

<Assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")>
```

Note that the .NET Core 7.0 project does not have an AssemblyInfo.vb file. Again, I know that I can create it but it is really necessary when the assembly version is already specified in the *.vbproj file of a .NET Core project and properly reflected in the project settings page like I shown in the screenshot at the beginning of this post?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by setting the [GenerateAssemblyInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#generatedassemblyinfofile) property to `true` in all the *.vbproj files of the affected projects.

So as I supposed there was no real need to manually recreate the AssemblyInfo.vb / AssemblyInfo.cs in a .NET Core project.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props) says:

> The GenerateAssemblyInfo property controls AssemblyInfo attribute
> generation for the project. The default value is true. Use false to
> disable generation of the file.
>
> When the GenerateAssemblyInfo value is true, package-related project
> properties are transformed into assembly attributes.

However, the default value at least for upgraded projects (using the .NET Upgrade Assistant CLI Tool or the Visual Studio extension) is always `false`.

---

Now, the easy way to fix this in a solution containing various projects is to press the hotkey combination **CTRL** + **H** to show the "Find and replace" window in Visual Studio, then search and replace in the entire solution this:

```
<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
```

For this:

```
<GenerateAssemblyInfo>true</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
```

And build the project. Now all the messages suggesting "Mark assemblies with assembly version" should disappear, and the 'details' tab in the properties window of the generated assembly in Windows Explorer should display properly all the properties:

[image]